# onPayloadReceived Nearby connections 2.0 doesn't receive File payload

Tags: google-play-services, google-nearby

```java
@Override
public void onPayloadReceived(String endpointId, Payload payload) {
  if (payload.getType() == Payload.Type.BYTES) {
    String payloadFilenameMessage = new String(payload.asBytes(), "UTF-8");
    addPayloadFilename(payloadFilenameMessage);
  } else if (payload.getType() == Payload.Type.FILE) {
    // Add this to our tracking map, so that we can retrieve the payload later.
    incomingPayloads.add(payload.getId(), payload);
  }
}
```

The issue is that the payload.getType() == Payload.Type.FILE condition is never true, only the Payload.Type.BYTES condition is true.

The sendPayload() snippet is from the [Exchange Data API page](https://developers.google.com/nearby/connections/android/exchange-data%20()).

```java
// The URI of the file selected by the user.
Uri uri = resultData.getData();

// Open the ParcelFileDescriptor for this URI with read access.
ParcelFileDescriptor pfd = getContentResolver().openFileDescriptor(uri, "r");
Payload filePayload = Payload.fromFile(pfd);

// Finally, send the file payload.
Nearby.Connections.sendPayload(endpointId, filePayload);
```

I know it's a duplicate, but I haven't found any working solution in web (regarding sending files) at least to compare my code with (unfinished medium article (text), walkie talkie app (stream), and fragments of from documentation)

here's sources https://github.com/salexwm/FilesExchange

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your code to send the file payload is commented out at https://github.com/salexwm/FilesExchange/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/test/filesexchange/ShareService.java#L199 (and it hasn't been updated since you posted this question, so could that be it?)

Comment: code from line #L199 moved to #L473 as suggested previously and added thread sleep (simplest way i could think off) to make 100% sure it waits for receiver to be ready, but still no result